# Issue with verification library (ECDSA) when trying to convert public key from SendGrid using Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid

I am working on a project where I am trying to process open and click events from [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). I set up a webhook following their [instructions](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook) and am receiving pushes of data successfully. When bypassing the signature validation, I can store the data.

I am using the signed event requests and can see the headers for the signature and timestamp come through:

```
"X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature"
"X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp"
```

I am attempting to convert the public key that SendGrid provided me to an ECDSA string so I can compare it and verify the signature in the header.

To do this I installed the [ECDSA library](https://github.com/starkbank/ecdsa-php). When sending the public key to the conversion function I get the following error:

```
gmp_init(): Argument #1 ($num) is not an integer string
```

I have also tried using the [SendGrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php), however, it uses the same ECDSA library and ends up with the same error message. It states...

```
$publicKey = 'base64-encoded public key';

$eventWebhook = new EventWebhook();
$ecPublicKey = $eventWebhook->convertPublicKeyToECDSA($publicKey);
```

The public key that SendGrid supplies is base64 encoded as expected by the ECDSA library. I have tried sending it encoded, decoded and everything in between :)

The conversion function then calls the ECDSA PublicKey class:

```
public function convertPublicKeyToECDSA($publicKey)
{
    return PublicKey::fromString($publicKey);
}
```

[publickey.php](https://github.com/starkbank/ecdsa-php/blob/master/src/publickey.php)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ZcomZ.  Did you have to make any additional changes to get this working?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for an intriguing question which got me into a section of SendGrid's Helper Library for PHP that I'd yet to explore – or even know about.

I created [a small PHP project](https://github.com/settermjd/sengrid-webhook-receiver), using [the Mezzio framework](https://docs.mezzio.dev/mezzio/), with my complete working solution. The key file to concentrate on is *src/App/src/Handler/SendGridWebhookHandler.php*.

However, the core of the functionality that worked for me, which you can see below, is pretty similar to what you shared in your code examples.

```
$eventWebHook = new EventWebhook();
$verifiedSignature = $eventWebHook->verifySignature(
    $eventWebHook->convertPublicKeyToECDSA($publicKey),
    $requestBody,
    $signature,
    $timestamp
);
```

- `$signature` is the value in the `X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature` header
- `$timestamp` is the value in the `X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp` header
- `$requestBody` is the contents of the body of the request
- `$publicKey` is the public key generated after clicking "Generate Verification Key.", as per [the documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook-security-features#enable-the-signed-event-webhook).

Let me know if it doesn't work for you, or if you have any questions about the code or why I've done things as I have.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I'm just starting to implement PHP authentication and I too am receiving the same error message as ZcomZ.  "gmp_init(): Argument #1 ($num) is not an integer string".  I've checked and double-checked the values I'm using, but to no avail.  Do you have any further insight?

Comment: I ran the test.php file from your project verbatim on my local machine, and it fails converting the public key with the gmp_init() error.  I'm almost wondering if it's a local platform error of some sort?

Comment: I had assumed the code would be using a more recent version of the starbank/ECDSA library.  Once I realized it was presuming a 0.* version I was able to make it work with 2.1.0 by changing line 25 of EventWebhook to: 
`return PublicKey::fromDer(base64_decode($publicKey));`

Comment: Jumping in late here, but yes, spot on... I did exactly that too. Literally banged my head on this for daaaays